# Browser does not render phpinfo()

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, phpinfo

I have a php file at http://lohray.com/info1.php that is just -

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

The page does not render on my browsers (I have tried chrome and firefox), however, `wget` fetches all the HTML. What might be going wrong? My apache / php are running on an EC2 instance.

Using the developer tools, I can see that I have received a 200 header with `X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10`.

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't render?  Do you see the raw PHP, or what?

Comment: I see a blank page. And on checking for the source, I see some incomplete HTML. I also tried to check it from my phone and do not see any HTML rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I figured out the problem. Apparently my university (Texas Tech University, Lubbock) network administrators tried to detect incoming phpinfo() output and blocked it! When I disconnect from WiFi and use LTE connection to access the site, I see the complete HTML and it renders fine.

Also, I tried to see the page from a remote proxy called http://www.surf-anon.com/ and it renders fine :-)

Thank you for the comments. It did give me a few tips.

The length to which some people go on the name of security! Disgusting!

Comment: This is one of those beloved "WTF" moments that I will never forget... good call!  Would you mind also marking this answer correct?  As benign as it may seem, I bet you anything a future Texas Tech University student will come looking one day... :)

Comment: I will have to wait for 2 days to mark my own answer correct.